# Firebase: reading data from firestore in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial).

I had this working before I tried to reconfigure my firebase.js config so that I could include authentication in the app.

I am trying to read from a collection in my app, with the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let options = [];
    // console.log(Firebase.db.collection("abs_for_codes"));
    // Firebase.db.return
    console.log(Firebase.db);
    Firebase.db
      .collection("abs_for_codes")
      .get()
      .then(
        function(querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            options.push({
              value: doc.data().title.replace(/( )/g, ""),
              label: doc.data().title + " - ABS " + doc.id
            });
          });
```

This all worked, until I redefined the firebase config.

Previously, that config file defined a firebase const as follows:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import firestore from "firebase/firestore";
import app from 'firebase/app';

const Firebase = app.initializeApp(config);

export default Firebase;
```

Now, I have:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    firebase.initializeApp(config).firestore();
    this.auth = firebase.auth();
    // this.db = app.database();

    // this.db = app.firebase.database()
    this.db = firebase.firestore();

  }  
}
export default Firebase;
```

When I try to use this, I can log Firebase in the app, which produces this output:

```
class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    firebase.initializeApp(config).firestore();
    this.auth = firebase.auth();
    // this.db = app.database();

    // this.db = app.firebase.database()
    this.db = firebase.firestore();

  }
```

I'm expecting to be able to log Firebase.db to return the firestore, but it produces undefined.

Then, when I try to access the collection in the firestore, I get an error that says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

I have seen [this post](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1469) which suggests it's a problem to do with the database not being found - rather than a collection issue.

The only difference between the old way of defining the database and the new way is that it's inside a class method instead of a const.

Is there something extra required if the firebase config is setup in a class?

Comment: Someone really needs to rewrite this tutorial, this like the fifth or sixth question you have asked about it. Maybe just find a better tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **create an instance** of the Firebase [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) to access its properties.

Change

```
Firebase.db
   .collection("abs_for_codes")
   .get()
   .then(querySnapshot => {
     // do something here
   });
```

to

```
const firebase = new Firebase();
firebase.db
   .collection("abs_for_codes")
   .get()
   .then(querySnapshot => {
     // do something here
   });
```